# Joomla Framework folder "libraries" missing

Tags: joomla-framework-1.x, libraries, cli

I'm having difficulties when trying to implement the example given on https://docs.joomla.org/Framework:Creating_a_Stand-alone_Application#Examples

I'm trying to do the first example and I'm getting an error:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../libraries/import.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\AppServ\www\framework\examples\hello.php on line 5

```
define('_JEXEC', 1); define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(FILE));

require '../libraries/import.php';

class HelloWorld extends JApplicationCli { public function execute() { $this->out('Hello World'); } }

JApplicationCli::getInstance('HelloWorld')->execute();
```

I came to check the files and there is no libraries folder or import.php file. Both composer and the framework are installed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doc page references a dead version of the project (joomla/joomla-framework which hasn't seen activity for a half-decade or more) which is a good indication that the rest of it is outdated as well. The current project files are at https://github.com/joomla-framework and the official site is https://framework.joomla.org

For a current example application, try looking at joomla/framework.joomla.org on github and see if that can help you get started.

Comment: That's what i thought. I didn't see any indications that it was dead haha. Thank you!